# How to use a vaiable declared in base class froma derived class

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a base class which uses a variable in ones of its methods and also a derived class that needs the same vaiable in its methods.
Below are the details

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
 protected Transition transition;
 public event EventHandler ActionComplete;
 private string abc;

 Public string ABC
 { 
    get{ return abc;}
    set { abc = value;} 
 }

 public void TransitionState(BaseClass obj)
 {
    ActionComplete(this, null);
 }
 public abstract void RequestSomeAction(Transition obj);

}

internal class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    //do i need to create transition variable again here
    internal new Transition transition;

    //this  parameter's value (here obj) should be assigned to the base class,

    public override void RequestSomeAction(Transition obj)
    {        
        //is below code correct. 
        stateTransition = obj;
        base.transition= transition;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the new transition variable and base.transition? If you make a variabele protected in the 'base class' you can just use it directly in the 'child class' that extends that class!?

Comment: This means there is no need for declaring internal new Transition transition;i dont need to call base.transition? i can just call transition?

Comment: @starz26 If you let DerivedClass extend BaseClass that has the protected variable transition in it, the DerivedClass has instant access to that variable. This means you can just use (this.)transition in the DerivedClass!

Comment: What if i have a property ABC in the BaseClass and how do child class access tht. is it with the name of the property (ABC) or with the variable (this.abc)?

Comment: this.ABC == ABC ??? The 'this' keyword is never really necessary except when it is used on its own

Answer (score 0):

First if you don't need to redeclare the variable, don't.  You can just use the protected property.

```
this.transition
```

---

If you need 2 copies of the variable with the same name (i can't think of any case when you would need this) then you are technically 'hiding' versus overridding  so you could do:

```
base.transition
```

or the same

```
((BaseClass)this).transition
```

[MSDN on base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691362%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not promoting it!  I was just facilitating, sometimes people want to do bad things.  :)

Comment: Facilitating crime is also a crime :P